# How to add rows dynamically - jquery with ajax php combination?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is my table structure.[image]

This is my output.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<table width="100%" id="controltable" border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>
        Product Name
    </th>

    <th>
        Product Price
    </th>

    <th >
        Quantity
    </th>

    <th >
        Calculate Price
    </th>

    <th >
        Amount
    </th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <?php
            echo '<select style="padding: 5px;" id="selectprice" name="prodlist">';
            echo '<option value="">Select Product</option>';
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prod_list");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $get_prod = $row['prod_name'];
                echo '<option value='.$get_prod.'>'.$get_prod.'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="price" id="hiddenconstvalue"  value=""/>';
            ?>

            <?php
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenresult" id="hiddenresult"  value=""/>';
            ?>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div id="output_frame"></div>
    </td>

    <td>
        <?php echo '<input type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="qnty" id="qnty"  value=""/>';?>
    </td>

    <td>
        <?php echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration: none;" onClick="show_price()">Calculate</a>'; ?>
    </td>

    <td>
        <div id="result"></div>

    </td>

</tr>

</table>

**Javascript Code**
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#selectprice').on('change', function() {


 $.get("get_price.php?prodId="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {

     $('input[name=price]').val(data);
     document.getElementById('output_frame').innerHTML = data;
    });
});
    });


   function show_price()
    {

     var textValue1 = document.getElementById('hiddenconstvalue').value;
     var textValue2 = document.getElementById('qnty').value;

     document.getElementById('result').value = textValue1 * textValue2;
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = textValue1 * textValue2;

    }
```

Here everything is working fine. When user selects a product say strepsils as shown in the figure, it will automatically fetch the price of the product. I implemented this by using ajax. After choosing the product the price will be listed and the user is allowed to enter the quantity. So when clicked on calculate the price will be caclulated. Now what I need is, if user wants to add more fileds say second product as vinly it should automatically append to the above table and the overall grand price should be calculated. How to do that? Please help.

Comment: You seem to have a race condition. What if the user changes the product and clicks the button before the response from the AJAX request arrives? The `#hiddenconstvalue` element will be updated, but the `#result` element will be recalculated based on old data. (Don't forget: if this is running in the real world then network connections are liable to be much slower than they are in your test setup.) Why don't you call `show_price` from the AJAX response handler, as well as the button handler? Then the user won't even need to press the button when they change the product.

Comment: Oh how to do that bro? any suggestions?

Comment: But anyhow when the product changes the price will also change, so it won't be a problem right?

Comment: The price doesn't change immediately. It's done via an AJAX request. This is asynchronous, which means that the response doesn't arrive immediately, and other code (possibly including the click handler) runs before the response arrives. (If you're running the client and server on the same machine, or even on the same network, then the connection is probably so fast that you can't reproduce this bug.) I'm saying you should add the line `show_price();` inside the function that begins `function( data ) {`, after the code that's already there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Ajax call returns HTML table row data, you can do the following

```
jQuery('#myTable tbody').append(response.html);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There must be a button. So if user clicks on it should append a row with product name listed in dropdown.